# No network connection in Xamarin.Forms project iOS when released

Tags: ios, rest, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have created a Xamarin.Forms project for iOS and Android. Everything is working as expected in the simulator and when I deploy to my own developer device via Visual Studio on Mac, but when I archive the project for release/test in TestFlight, the app is not getting any data from the webservice. I have done some logging in the webservice end, and have confirmed that the request from the HttpClient never reaches the rest service.

You can see a part of the RestService I have in the Xamarin.Forms PCL.

The webserver where the service is running uses a secure connection SSL/TLS.

```
    HttpClient _client;

    public RestService()
    {
        _client = new HttpClient();
    }

    public async Task<ObservableCollection<Event>> GetEventsAsync(int seasonId)
    {
        ObservableCollection<Event> Events = new ObservableCollection<Event>();

        try
        {
            Uri uri = new Uri(string.Format(Constants.Constants.EVENT,
                                        string.Empty) + "/" + seasonId);

        HttpResponseMessage response = await _client.GetAsync(uri);

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            Events = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollection<Event>>(content);
        }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }

        return Events;
    }
```

I have tried a lot of different things regarding the build profile, linking options and so on, but seems like nothing works.

The strange thing is why it works on my device, even if I deploy the release profile to my phone, but not when I deploy it to the iTunes Connect.

Comment: Add some logging in the mobile app too, so that we can see what the exact exception is.

Comment: does your app have internet permissions enabled?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Jason, you were right, there the internet permissions were not correct. I changed it to the following in the Info.plist

```
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
            <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
            <true/>
    </dict>
```

And then I adjusted the build settings to the following for the Release iPhone profile:

[image]

Comment: You can mark this answer later so that we can help more people with same problem:).